# How to draw a customized box in Tradingview?

Tags: rectangles, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot a customized box in Tradingview. I want the box to be plotted at the last price of the Chikou Span and have borders as follows:

```
left: latest data;
right: latest data + 5 time periods;
top: price*1.1;
bottom: price*.9
```

I want the box to be plotted on the Chikou Span graph that is plotted over the main price graph. I don't want it to be plotted in a seperate window

Answer (score 0):

so i managed to get to what i want:

The `overlay=true` allows the graph to be plotted over the original graph

```
indicator("CS Box",overlay = true)
```

time is set in milliseconds so choose your input time value accordingly

```
var b = box.new(time-35*24*3600*1000, 1.1*close, time-26*24*3600*1000, close,
xloc=xloc.bar_time, border_style=line.style_dashed)
box.set_lefttop(b, time-35*24*3600*1000, close*1.1)
box.set_rightbottom(b,time-26*24*3600*1000, close*0.9 )
box.set_bgcolor(b, color.green)
```

Also, you can hold the CTRL key and select any built in function and it will give you the parameters required for that.